# Why if I delete input I get a different result?

Tags: pine-script

There is something I don't understand.
In the code below, why if I remove `input` and replace it with `length = 50` then I have a completely different result

Here is the full code, experiment by replacing `length = input(50)` by `length = 50`

```
//@version=5
indicator("Andean Oscillator")

length = input(50)

var alpha = 2/(length+1)

var up1 = 0.,var up2 = 0.
var dn1 = 0.,var dn2 = 0.

C = close
O = open

up1 := nz(math.max(C, O, up1[1] - (up1[1] - C) * alpha), C)
up2 := nz(math.max(C * C, O * O, up2[1] - (up2[1] - C * C) * alpha), C * C)

dn1 := nz(math.min(C, O, dn1[1] + (C - dn1[1]) * alpha), C)
dn2 := nz(math.min(C * C, O * O, dn2[1] + (C * C - dn2[1]) * alpha), C * C)

bull = math.sqrt(dn2 - dn1 * dn1)
bear = math.sqrt(up2 - up1 * up1)

plot(bull, 'Bullish Component', #089981)
plot(bear, 'Bearish Component', #f23645)
```

Comment: What is the difference in the result? Can you please [edit] the question to clarify? I presume `length = 50` simply sets the length to an integer, whereas `input()` normally asks for user input and possibly sees "50" as the 50th ASCII character or something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because when you have `length = 50`, `alpha` becomes an `integer` and therefore its value is set to zero.

You need to add the `float` keyword to either `length` or `alpha`.

```
float length = 50
var alpha = 2/(length+1)
```

or

```
length = 50
var float alpha = 2/(length+1)
```